# Use of variables in Django template {% block %} tags

Tags: python, django, templates, block

The main question is how can I programatically choose what block to put some content in. The following is working in a different project, but in a fresh project this does not work for some reason. I'm using the same (default) template context processors on the same machine for both projects.

I have a base template that goes something like this

```
...
{% block Title %}<h1>Whoo</h1>{% endblock %}

{% block Content %}<p>Hi there</p>{% endblock %}
...
```

And an extending template like this

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
...
{% block myblock.name %} <p> {{ myblock.content }} </p> {% endblock %}

<p> {{ myblock.name }} </br> {{ myblock.content }} </p>
...
```

And rendering as such

```
myblock = { 'name': 'Title', 'content': 'stuff' }
return render_to_response( 'extended.html', {'myblock': myblock}, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

I expect to get, and get on the first project:

```
...
<p> stuff <p>
<p>Hi there</p>
<p> Title </br> stuff </p>
...
```

But on the second project I get

```
...
<h1>Whoo</h1>
<p>Hi there</p>
<p> Title </br> stuff </p>
...
```

So on the second project, the myblock dict is passed and processed by the template but it seems that the myblock.name in {% block myblock.name %} is interpreted as a literal and not a variable. Any ideas on how to force Django to evaluate a variable inside a {% block %} tag?

Comment: Works for me as in your first example. Are you sure the code is the same in both projects?

Comment: Checked checked and rechecked :(

Answer (score 2):

You should take another look at the documentation about [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance).

> ... the block tag defines [...] blocks that child templates can fill
>   in. All the block tag does is to tell the template engine that a child
>   template may override those portions of the template.

But you don't assign a variable to a block directly in a view as you are trying to do.

And  `{% block myblock.name %}` looks strange too.

To receive the result you are expecting I'd say the template should rather look like this

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block Title %}<p>{{ myblock.content }}</p>{% endblock %}
```

---

Assuming you are using a recent version of Django you could even simplify things using the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut in your view:

```
return render(request, 'extended.html', {'name': 'Title', 'content': 'stuff'})
```

Which would lead to a template like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block Title %}<p>{{ content }}</p>{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I want to avoid hardcoding the block that my content will be put into so that if i have five different blocks I can choose which block to use for what content from inside the view function.