# is there a way to set name of a block using variables in django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am making some generic templates for my projects like the message template given below.

```
{% extends base_name %}

{% block main-contents %}

    <h2>{{ message_heading }}</h2>

    <div class="alert alert-{{ box_color|default:"info" }}">
        {{ message }}

        {% if btn_1_text and btn_1_url %}
            <a href="{{ btn_1_url }}" class="btn btn-{{ btn_1_color }}">{{ btn_1_text }}</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if btn_2_text and btn_2_url %}
            <a href="{{ btn_2_url }}" class="btn btn-{{ btn_2_color }}">{{ btn_2_text }}</a>
        {% endif %}

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I can set the name of the base template through template variables. My question is whether there is a method to set the name of the block using template variables. Usually I use the block name main-contents for almost all of my project. But that is not granted for all the projects. If this is not possible using template is there a way to rename the block using python code ?

Comment: Check out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316180/use-of-variables-in-django-template-block-tags might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hack. I dont know if this has any after effects. Can any one verify this ?

```
def change_block_names(template, change_dict):
    """
    This function will rename the blocks in the template from the
    dictionary. The keys in th change dict will be replaced with
    the corresponding values. This will rename the blocks in the 
    extended templates only.
    """

    extend_nodes = template.nodelist.get_nodes_by_type(ExtendsNode)
    if len(extend_nodes) == 0:
        return

    extend_node = extend_nodes[0]
    blocks = extend_node.blocks
    for name, new_name in change_dict.items():
        if blocks.has_key(name):
            block_node = blocks[name]
            block_node.name = new_name
            blocks[new_name] = block_node
            del blocks[name]


tmpl_name = 'django-helpers/twitter-bootstrap/message.html'
tmpl1 = loader.get_template(tmpl_name)
change_block_names(tmpl1, {'main-contents': 'new-main-contents})
```

This seems to work for now. I want to know if this method has any after effects or other issues.